# SyntaxError show in python

Tags: python

I'm facing this error. Please let me know how can I do for it.

My Python Code:

```
import socket
listener = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
listener.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSERADDR, 1)
listener.bind(("192.168.5.129", 4444)
listener.listen(1)
print("[+] Waiting incoming connection")
connection, address = listener.accept()
print("[+] Got a connection from " + str(address))
while True:
    command = raw_input("Shell$ ")
    connection.send(command)
    result = connection.recv(1024)
    print(result)
```

[image: Erro show in this image]

Comment: Do you mean to have `**import` instead of `import`?  Also you have mismatched parentheses in your call to listener.bind.

Comment: It's usually better if you add errors as text and not as screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have forgot to close the bracket. Replace `listener.bind(("192.168.5.129", 4444)` with `listener.bind(("192.168.5.129", 4444))`

Answer (score 0):

In line 4 (line 10 in your editor), you need to close bracket at the end of the line.

```
listener.bind(("192.168.5.129", 4444)) <---bracket close
```